# Why do i get this error when initializing Bean in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I have to make follow and old tutorial from spring that initializes a rest service with spring ,the problem is since its from 8 years ago a lot has changed in the diffrent aspect of annotations.
So i have the folllowing code Employee.java:

```
package payrool;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {

        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
                && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", role='" + this.role + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

And the repository for it EmployeeRepository.java:

```
package payrool;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

with the connection to database in LoadDatabase.java:

```
package payrool;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
class LoadDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {

        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

Now ,when i try to run the code in my main app

```
package payrool;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class NonrestApplication{

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NonrestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'initDatabase' defined in class path resource [payrool/LoadDatabase.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'initDatabase' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in payrool.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class payrool.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at payrool.NonrestApplication.main(NonrestApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in payrool.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class payrool.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class payrool.Employee
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I have tried anything but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot 3.x?

Comment: Yes ,im using spring boot 3.0.1 .

Comment: tl;dr: you are using the wrong annotation in class `Emplyoee`. Use `jakarta.persistence.Entity` instead of `javax.persistence.Entity`.